# HowTo Enlarge volumeGroup

Tags: partition, lvm, disk, parted

I run an ubuntu server and used cloneZilla to uprade my SSD from 256G to 1TByte.
My /dev/sda3 has now a 1TB partition, but I can use only 256G as volumeGroup.

How can I enlarge my volumeGroup?

Thanks

```
parted print list
    Model: ATA Samsung SSD 870 (scsi)
    Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
    Partition Table: gpt
    Disk Flags:
    
    Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
    1      1049kB  5145kB  4096kB                     bios_grub
    2      5145kB  6296MB  6291MB  ext4
    3      6296MB  1000GB  994GB
    
    
    Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
    Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 254GB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
    Partition Table: loop
    Disk Flags:
    
    Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
    1      0,00B  254GB  254GB  ext4

vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <236,97 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              60664
  Alloc PE / Size       60664 / <236,97 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               dfc5HC-YUBS-ofyZ-h8A4-LaeD-lFuA-PlhyGL
```

Comment: How did sda3 end up being that large? I.e., what did you do to resize it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize the physical volume; as root:

```
pvresize /dev/sda3
```

The volume group will follow suit.

Comment: Thanks!

 `pvresize /dev/sda3`
 did the job.

followed by these 2 commands:
`lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

 resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`